plateform scams solana
I recently fell victim to an exchange scam. I sent 8000 USDT from my Binance platform to a site called < solsit.com >, believing it was a legitimate exchange. However, after completing the transaction, I was surprised to find that the site had unexpectedly banned me. Unfortunately, my attempts to contact platform support were unsuccessful. I now fear that I have lost my funds irreversibly. I am looking for advice on what steps to take to try to recover my funds or at least report this scam to the relevant authorities.
Can anyone help me on this please
